# window.open on iOS opens on the same browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, window.open

i've created a custom social sharing bar and when you click on a link, a javascript popup opens up showing the sharing panel for each social network.

the html:

```
<div class="js-popup" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://google.com">
  facebook
</div>
```

the js function

```
$(".js-popup").click(function() {
  var leftPosition, topPosition;
  leftPosition = window.screen.width / 2 - (566 / 2 + 10);
  topPosition = window.screen.height / 2 - (576 / 2 + 50);
  var url = $(this).data("href");
  window.open(
    url,
    "myWindow",
    "status = 1, height = 576, width = 566, resizable = 0,left=" +
      leftPosition +
      ",top=" +
      topPosition +
      ",screenX=" +
      leftPosition +
      ",screenY=" +
      topPosition +
      ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no"
  );
});
```

see a live codepen here: https://codepen.io/vlrprbttst/pen/RgNZPq

this works great everywhere but there's one strange thing happening on iOS. On iOS the codepen works fine, everytime i click on a button, a new tab opens up. when i implement it elsewhere, for example here: http://valeriopierbattista.com/blog/understanding-git-and-github/ (bottom of the page), everytime i click on a button the page loads on the same open tab.

for example:

- i click on facebook
- a facebook tab fires up in the browser
- i don't close the tab and go back to the page
- i click on twitter
- apparently nothing happens but in fact the twitter link is opening in the tab i left open from my last click,  so what the user perceives is that the button is broken.

this happens both on ipad and iphone. why does the codepen work as expected, and on the other site not? the code is exactly the same. what am i missing?

Comment: same window name gets reused.

Comment: @epascarello ah! that's a good point.. what would be the fix? and why isn't this happening on the codepen?

Comment: set a unique name or use _blank

Comment: @epascarello if i use blank the window width and height are not honored :/ how can i set a unique name so it doesnt get reused?

Comment: generate a radom number? append it to the name

Comment: this worked! http://prntscr.com/fg8owh thanks :)